# Need detailed instructions on how to make a football image rotate using Blender 2.83

Tags: animation

I am a newbie with Blender (Version 2.83) on Windows 10.
I want to make a simple 3D animation for rotating a football. Now I have one footabll image in the Blender IDE.
But I can't find any good step-by-step guide. What I want is: to rotate the footall image for 360 degress within 60 seconds, I don't know which axis, I think Z-axis should be OK.

I read some documents, but it didn't help me, just made me more confused.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to rotate the ball as an object (the question is a little hard to understand, sorry), the best way would be to **keyframe animate** it.

At the bottom of the layout there is a timeline, pull that up so you can see it a bit better.

Keyframe animation works this way: you define a bunch of key poses that will occur at given times. The computer then will fill in the transitions making a smooth animation without much effort.

So to spin the ball:

1. Select the ball, make sure you are on frame 0.
2. Press <kbd>I</kbd> and select "rotation".
3. Move the bar a few frames forwards, for example 20.
4. Rotate the ball 90 degrees (any direction)
5. Press <kbd>I</kbd> again and select "rotation".

If you stopped now and pressed the play button and started from the beginning, you will see the ball spin... a quarter of a rotation. So repeat this process to have the ball make an entire 360-degree spin.

Now open a graph editor window with the ball selected and you will see a bunch of points. Each point represents the value inside a certain attribute of the object (e.g. rotation x) at the given time.

Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all and <kbd>V</kbd>. Choose "Vector". This will make the ball's rotation smoother. Then press <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the side panel. Go to properties and add a "Cycles" modifier to every attribute that was animated. This will make the ball spin infinitely.

That's it! Keyframe animation is a very useful animation method because the user only needs to specify a few poses and the computer will fill the rest.